# Getting confused about window.getSelection() api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am using a div with html5 contenteditable="true" attribute to use it as an editor. I am inserting words at caret position using window.getSelection() api.

But its behaving differently in IE11.

When I type window.getSelection() in chrome console after page loaded, it's returning body element.

[image]

Same thing in IE-11 console returning text node, due to which inserting text at caret position is not working properly.

[image]

Here is the code to pasteTextAtCaret() function

```
var ele = $(".editor");
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html) {
                    if(!ele.is(':focus')) {ele.focus();}
                    var sel, range;
                    if (window.getSelection) {
                        // IE9 and non-IE
                        sel = window.getSelection();
                        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                            range.deleteContents();

                            // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
                            // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
                            var el = document.createElement("div");
                            el.innerHTML = html;
                            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
                            while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
                                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
                            }
                            range.insertNode(frag);

                            // Preserve the selection
                            if (lastNode) {
                                range = range.cloneRange();
                                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                                range.collapse(true);
                                sel.removeAllRanges();
                                sel.addRange(range);
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
                        // IE < 9
                        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
                    }
                }
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: use document.activeElement instead of if(!ele.is(':focus')) {ele.focus();}. First test by commenting out the line.... I think the focus event is bubbled to the top (body) in IE.

Comment: Yes you are correct. How do I set the activeelement without using focus?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out that in my css I used following property for the editor whcih is causing the problem.

```
-ms-user-select: none
```